# Android, Why my custom square ImageView on emulator has curve corner while on real device doesn't have?

Tags: android, imageview, custom-component, curve

I need to have square image view with curved corner. Everything seems okay and Preview of IntelliJ Idea shows it's working fine. However corners are not curve when I run it on real device.

My custom ImgeView:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final String TAG = "SquareImageView";

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int h = this.getMeasuredHeight();
        int w = this.getMeasuredWidth();

        setMeasuredDimension(w, w);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Path clipPath = new Path();
        float radius = 20.0f;
        float padding = radius / 2;
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();

        clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(padding, padding, w - padding, h - padding), radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

XML of layout:

```
<com.belldigital.widget.SquareImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/Black"
                android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_default_logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"/>
```

Screenshot of emulator:

[image]

Screenshot of real device:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 10));

    }
     public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
            Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                    .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

            final int color = 0xff424242;
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
            final float roundPx = pixels;

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

            return output;
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to have square image. That's why I did it like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: I tested it. Works fine :) Thank you #Kirit